# PHP Losing values in an 2-diminational associative array after they have been modified

Tags: php, arrays

I'm baffled about a problem I have with PHP and a 2-dim associative array.  I'm in a class for PHP and the instructor is rather clueless.

I declare the array to make it global with some information.  I use an html form to display the data from the array.  I modify two null values in the array with an html form "calc" button.  Everything works great.  The array is updated.  I then use a form "order" button to create a text file using the array values.  This is when it gets weird. The modified values in the array are gone.   I can create and save the text file within the $_Post calc If statement just fine.  Same text using the $_Post submit button - gives me the old null values.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd'>

<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>

<head>

<title>Online Orders</title>

</head>

    <body>
    <?php

        function DisplayTable(){
            echo "<h2 style ='text-align:center'>Online Order</h2>\n";
            echo "<p>Enter the desired items you wish to order:</p>\n";

            echo "<form action='OnlineOrders.php' method ='POST'>";
            echo "<table style='background-color:lightgray' border='1' width='80%'>";           
            echo "<tr><td width = '10%' style = 'text-align:center'><span style = 'font-weight:bold'>Item</span></td>
            <td width = '40%' style = 'text-align:center'><span style = 'font-weight:bold'> 
                        Description</span></td>";
            echo "<td width = '10%' style = 'text-align:center'><span style = 'font-weight:bold'>Price</span></td>";
            echo "<td width = '10%' style = 'text-align:center'><span style = 'font-weight:bold'>Quantity</span></td>";
            echo "<td width = '10%' style = 'text-align:center'><span style = 'font-weight:bold'>Total</span></td></tr>";


            //foreach($products as $item){

            global $products;
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($products); ++$i){
                $name = key($products);
                echo "<tr><td style = 'text-align:left'>" . $name . "</td>";
                echo "<td style = 'text-align:left'>" . $products[$name]['Description']. "</td>";       
                echo "<td style = 'text-align:center'>" . $products[$name]['Price']. "</td>";
                if($products[$name]['Quantity'] > 0)
                    $value = $products[$name]['Quantity'];
                else
                    $value = "";
                echo "<td style = 'text-align:left'><input type='text' name = 'quantity[" . $name ."]' value = $value></td>";
                if($products[$name]['Total'] > 0)
                    echo "<td style = 'text-align:left'>" . $products[$name]['Total']. "</td>";
                else
                    echo "<td></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                next($products);
            }
            echo "</table>";
            echo "<p></p>";
            echo "<input type ='submit' name='submit' value='Order' />";
            echo "<input type ='submit' name='calc' value='Calculate' />";
            echo "</form>";     
        }   

        //creates data array
        $pencils = array("Price" => "1.50", "Description" =>"12pk of #2 pencils", "Quantity" => NULL, "Total" => NULL);
        $pens = array("Price" => "3.50", "Description" =>"12pk of Bic blue ink pens", "Quantity" => NULL, "Total" => NULL);
        $paper = array("Price" => "5.50", "Description" =>"6pk of letter-sized, 100 count paper pads", 
                    "Quantity" => NULL, "Total" => NULL);
        $stapler = array("Price" => "6.40", "Description" =>"Streamline stapler - black", "Quantity" => NULL, 
                    "Total" => NULL);
        $staples = array("Price" => "2.00", "Description" =>"Streamline staples, 5000 count", "Quantity" => NULL, 
                    "Total" => NULL);
        $products = array("Pencils" => $pencils, "Pens" => $pens, "Paper" => $paper, "Stapler" => $stapler, 
                        "Staples" => $staples);


//doesn't work right doesn't have updated values
//Uses the array to create a text file and saves it to the hard drive in a folder entitled "/OnlineOrders"  
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        global $products;
        $Dir = "OnlineOrders";
            if (is_dir($Dir)){
                echo "Products in order";
                //print_r($products);  //prints out the array as it was declared not modified!
                $SaveString = "Online Order\r\n\r\n";
                $SaveString .= date('m/d/Y') . "\r\n\r\n";
                $SaveString .= "Item\t\tPrice\t   Quantity\tTotal\r\n";
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($products); ++$i){
                    $name = key($products);
                //  if ($products[$name]['Quantity']>0){
                        $SaveString .= $name ."\t\t" . $products[$name]['Price'] ."\t\t". $products[$name]['Quantity'] .
                                        "\t" . $products[$name]['Total'] ."\r\n\r\n";                           

                //  }
                //  else
                //      echo "Nothing to write to file";
                    next($products);
                }
                $TimeStamp = date('Y_m_d_G_i');
                $SaveFileName  = "$Dir/order.$TimeStamp.txt";
                $fp = fopen($SaveFileName, "wb");
                if ($fp === FALSE){
                    echo "There was an error creating \"" . htmlentities($SaveFileName) . "\".<br />\n";                    
                }
                else {
                    if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {
                        if (fwrite($fp, $SaveString)>0)
                            echo "Successfully wrote to file \"" . htmlentities($SaveFileName) . "\".<br />\n";
                        else
                            echo "There was an error writing to file \"" . htmlentities($SaveFileName) . "\".<br />\n";
                        flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
                    }
                    else{
                        echo "There was an error locking file \"" . htmlentities($SaveFileName) . 
                             " for writing\".<br />\n";
                    }
                    fclose($fp);
                }   
            }
        echo "<p><a href='OnlineOrders.php'>Order Again?</p>\n";
    }
    //enter values into the quantity input items and addes qty and total to array and redisplays the html table with updated values
    else if(isset($_POST['calc'])){
        global $products;
        $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
        if(is_array($quantity)){
            foreach ($quantity as $item => $value){

                if($value <> NULL){
                    $amount = stripslashes($value);
                    if(is_numeric($amount) && ($amount > 0)){
                        $products[$item]['Quantity'] = $amount;
                        $products[$item]['Total'] = ($products[$item]['Price'] * $amount);
                    }
                    else
                        echo "<p>You must enter a number greater than 0 for $item's quantity</p>\n";
                }   
            }

            DisplayTable();
            //print_r($products);  //TEST - PRINTS OUT THE ARRAY WITH UPDATED VALUES CORRECTLY


//TESTING STARTS HERE - SAME CODE FROM submit button and it works
        $Dir = "OnlineOrders";
            if (is_dir($Dir)){
                $SaveString = "Online Order\r\n\r\n";
                $SaveString .= date('m/d/Y') . "\r\n\r\n";
                $SaveString .= "Item\t\tPrice\t   Quantity\tTotal\r\n";
                reset($products);
                for ($j = 0; $j < count($products); ++$j){  
                    $name = key($products);
                    if ($products[$name]['Quantity']>0){
                        $SaveString .= $name ."\t\t" . $products[$name]['Price'] ."\t\t". $products[$name]['Quantity'] .
                                        "\t" . $products[$name]['Total'] ."\r\n";
                    }
                    next($products);
                }
                $TimeStamp = date('Y_m_d_G_i');
                $SaveFileName  = "$Dir/order.$TimeStamp.txt";
                $fp = fopen($SaveFileName, "wb");
                if ($fp === FALSE){
                    echo "There was an error creating \"" . htmlentities($SaveFileName) . "\".<br />\n";                    
                }
                else {
                    if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {
                        if (fwrite($fp, $SaveString)>0)
                            echo "Successfully wrote to file \"" . htmlentities($SaveFileName) . "\".<br />\n";
                        else
                            echo "There was an error writing to file \"" . htmlentities($SaveFileName) . "\".<br />\n";
                        flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
                    }
                    else{
                        echo "There was an error locking file \"" . htmlentities($SaveFileName) . 
                             " for writing\".<br />\n";
                    }
                fclose($fp);
                }   
            }
//Testing Ends Here
        }
    }
    else
        DisplayTable();
    ?>
    </body> 

</html>
```

Comment: Please provide a simpler example. That's a lot of code and a rather vague explanation. It sounds like you expect changes to the array to persist between different requests though. If so, that's not gonna work.

Comment: They are simpler ways to work with arrays than using `key` and `next` ... `foreach`  would have served the same purpose

Comment: Baba - I was having problems grasping how to use the foreach with the 2-dim assoc. array.  It finally clicked this morning.  I had it backwards.  Thanks.

Comment: Please accept your answer below which will mark your question as answered which is how this site works (yes you can accept your own answer). Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

My programming "GOD" classmate who isn't even in my class educated me on how PHP and server-side processing works.  Basically, the Array does not live once you finish the processing.  When the page reloads, the default array is re-created with the default NULL values.  I created several functions and run the calculations for both the Calc button and Order buttons and amen it works correctly.